# Creating new seurat object with new matrix

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat, single-cell

I'm trying to do a cross-species comparison between the patient TME vs. the PTX TME to understand gene expression conservation. I have already converted between mouse and human genes giving me a resultant gene expression matrix that is just one set of (homologous) genes X cells for all mouse and human cells.

```
musGenes <- rownames(mouse_only)
# Basic function to convert mouse to human gene names
convertMouseGeneList <- function(x){
require("biomaRt")
h = useMart("ensembl", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
m = useMart("ensembl", dataset = "mmusculus_gene_ensembl")
genesV2 = getLDS(attributes = c("mgi_symbol"), filters = "mgi_symbol", values = x , mart = m, attributesL = c("hgnc_symbol"), martL = h, uniqueRows=T)
humanx <- unique(genesV2[, 2])
# Print the first 6 genes found to the screen
print(head(humanx))
return(humanx)
}
genes <- convertMouseGeneList(musGenes)
```

Now how do I create a new Seurat object with the converted mouse gene list, such as rename the matrix, so that the rownames/colnames are human symbols, rather than mouse symbols?

Comment: is [this thread](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/4515) useful? They do rename rownames of the just created seurat object.